# Agrupar resultado através de uma condicional

Tags: mysql, if, group-by, case, when

Gostaria de saber se no MySQL ou em qualquer outro Banco tem a possibilicade de usar GROUP BY com uma condicional.

Vou tentar explicar tenho uma coluna status que pode ter o valor true e false,
gostaria de agrupar apenas quando o valor for true.

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clausula `HAVING` pode ser usada para isso, como exemplo abaixo:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela 
GROUP BY status 
HAVING status = 'true'
```

Comment: funcionou, preciso que me tire uma duvida e caso eu queira trazer o status false, mas não agrupado teria como

Comment: SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE status = 'false'

Comment: quero trazer tanto o false como verdadeiro, mas quero agrupar apenas os verdadeiros tem como??